# DELETE a record by REST API without @HttpDelete

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, rest, delete

I need to make integration between Org1 and Org2. We created a callout POST. When we create an object in Org1, we also create an object in Org2. POST work. All is Ok. Now I need also delete an object in Org2, if External Id in this obj == Id in obj from Org1.

Something like that:

```
If(org2Object.ExternalId == org1Object.Id){
   Delete org2Object;
}
```

I try to delete a record from another org, but I don't know, how to write it right. My Delete callout:

```
private static Position__c pos = [SELECT Id, Name, Location__c, Job_Description__c, Salary_Range__c, Skills_Required__c, Education__c,
                       Hiring_Manager__r.Name, Email__c, Phone__c, Status__c
                       FROM Position__c WHERE Name = 'Title22'];

public static String getRequestBody(){
    Settings__c settings = [SELECT ConsumerKey__c, ClientSecret__c, Username__c, Password__c, SecurityToken__c
                            FROM Settings__c
                            WHERE Name = 'OurSettings'];  
    String consumerKey = settings.ConsumerKey__c;
    String consumerSecret = settings.ClientSecret__c;
    String username = settings.Username__c;
    String password = settings.Password__c + settings.SecurityToken__c;
    String request = 'grant_type=password&client_id=' + consumerKey +'&client_secret=' + consumerSecret +
                     '&username=' + username + '&password='+password;
    return request;
}


public static void deleteCalloutResponseContents(Id ourId){
    Http ourHttp = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = httpRequest('DELETE');
    HttpResponse response = ourHttp.send(request);
    OAuth2 objAuthenticationInfo = (OAuth2)JSON.deserialize(response.getbody(), OAuth2.class);

    if(objAuthenticationInfo.ACCESS_TOKEN != null){
        pos.Id = ourId;

        HttpRequest finalRequest = new HttpRequest();
        String jsonstr='{"Position_ID__c":"'+ ourId +'"}';

        finalRequest.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+ objAuthenticationInfo.ACCESS_TOKEN);
        finalRequest.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        finalRequest.setHeader('accept','application/json');
        finalRequest.setBody(jsonstr);
        finalRequest.setMethod('DELETE');

        request.setEndpoint(System.Label.Job_Advertisement_URL + '/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Job_Advertisement__c/ourId');
        response = ourHttp.send(finalRequest);
        System.debug('RESPONSE BODY: ' + response.getBody());
    }        
}

public class OAuth2{
        public String ACCESS_TOKEN{get;set;}    
    }
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

NB: this answer is partially invalidated because the poster changed the code in the question.

`HttpRequest` does not have a constructor that takes a string. Are you shadowing the object's name with a method `httpRequest`? That seems likely to produce confusion.

Regardless, the [sObject Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_query.htm) resource does not accept the `DELETE` method. To delete a record, you need to make a `DELETE`-method request to the [sObject Rows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_retrieve.htm) endpoint,

> /vXX.X/sobjects/**SObjectName**/**id**/

with your sObject's name (`Job__c`) and Id in the relevant positions.

Note that the `@HttpDelete` annotation is used for building *inbound* REST services, not making outbound callouts.

Comment: But how can I compare Id from record from Salesforce org 1 with a Id from record from Salesforce org 2? And delete only right record.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I updated it...

Answer (score 0):

To delete via External ID, use the External ID resource:

```
request.setEndpoint(
  System.Label.Job_Advertisement_URL + 
  '/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Job_Advertisement__c/Position_ID__c/'+ourId);
```

There is no need for a JSON body or the associated `Content-Type` header. If everything goes well, you will get a return status of 204.